# which implementation stack library use in c++?

Tags: c++, stack

I read that The ADT stack can be implemented using

An array

A linked list

The ADT list

But when I'm using the stack I just call stack library. Which of these implementation stack library use?

Comment: Which "stack library"? You mean the standard `std::stack`?

Comment: yes.........................

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::stack` is a container *adapter* that uses some other container as the underlying storage for the data. That defaults to `std::deque`, but you can specify another sequence such as `std::list` or `std::vector` if you prefer.

The requirements on the underlying container are pretty minimal -- if memory serves, it needs to support a `back()`, `push_back()`, `pop_back()`, `size()` and `swap()` (and the last two aren't really needed unless you use `stack::size()` or `stack::swap()`, which probably aren't all that common).